# Scan and connect BLE device using Node Js from Windows 10

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scan the BLE device using node js. but I am getting errors while running.
I have referred this Git Repo
https://github.com/noble/noble

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bluetooth-hci-socket'
Require stack:
- D:\BLE-node\node_modules\noble\lib\hci-socket\hci.js
- D:\BLE-node\node_modules\noble\lib\hci-socket\bindings.js
- D:\BLE-node\node_modules\noble\lib\resolve-bindings.js
- D:\BLE-node\node_modules\noble\index.js
- D:\BLE-node\app.js
```

Here is App.js

app.js

```
const Noble = require("noble");
const BeaconScanner = require("node-beacon-scanner");

var scanner = new BeaconScanner();

scanner.onadvertisement = (advertisement) => {
    var beacon = advertisement["iBeacon"];
    beacon.rssi = advertisement["rssi"];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(beacon, null, "    "))
};

scanner.startScan().then(() => {
    console.log("Scanning for BLE devices...");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: edited code @wcoder

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if `bluetooth-hci-socket` installed and declared correctly. (https://github.com/noble/node-bluetooth-hci-socket#windows)

Try to use the latest fork of noble: https://github.com/abandonware/noble